# In Bash: "find" command is ignoring "-type f" option

Tags: bash

I'm trying to extract a list of .mp3 files from a large directory, each of which is buried inside an album name directory and an artist name directory.
So I try to obtain a list of .mp3 files with this:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 echo
```

But the command seems to be ignoring the "-type f", and instead lists out every single directory & file.
Am I missing something very, very obvious?

SOME BETTER info: Went back & looked harder at my output. What I'm actually getting is the entire file path included in the .mp3 file name. So instead of "Like a Stone.mp3" it's more like "/Users/User/Music/Audioslave/Audioslave/05 Like a Stone.mp3". Any way to output the command with one file name per line--human friendly? –

Comment: Can't reproduce it on my computer. I copied your command and it works as expected.

Comment: You have directories that end with `.mp3`? Or is that part also being ignored? What operating system are you using? I cannot reproduce this either.

Comment: Try putting full path on front, e.g. /usr/bin/find ....

Comment: is it possible that you copied/pasted the command from the web somewhere? If so, sometimes the '-' that is copied isn't really a dash, but an emdash - and that can cause havoc...

Comment: RE: using dashes instead of emdashes: I went back, deleted every dash in command and replaced with a known-good dash. Same outcome.

Comment: What do you get from `find --version`?

Comment: SOME BETTER info: Went back & looked harder at my output. What I'm actually getting is the entire file path included in the .mp3 file name. So instead of "Like a Stone.mp3" it's more like "/Users/User/Music/Audioslave/Audioslave/05 Like a Stone.mp3". Any way to output the command with one file name per line--_human friendly_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you've clarified your question, it makes sense. Use the `basename` command:

```
find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 basename
```

This removes the directory part and just prints the file name part.

Comment: Greg: The basename command nailed it. Thanks much for your time!

Comment: Note that if you have more than one file, you probably need to add `-L 1` to the `xargs` command. The `basename` command expects only one argument.

Comment: @GregHewgill: `-n 1` does the same thing in this case and is probably clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting all the file names on one line because that's what you told it it to do.  The `find ... | xargs ... command` invokes `command` with multiple arguments. In this case, since the command is `echo`, you get all the arguments on one line.

You need something that prints each argument on one line. It turns out that the `printf` command is an easy way to do that. If you give it more arguments than are specified by the format string, it will start over from the beginning of the format string, looping until it runs out of arguments.

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 printf '%s\n'
```

This still invokes `printf` just once (or perhaps a few times if you have a *lot* of file names), but `printf` prints a newline for each argument.

But that still prints the full path, including the directory name, for each file. If you want just the file name, you can strip it off:

```
$ find . -type f -name '*.mp3' -print0 | xargs -0 printf '%s\n' | sed 's/.*\///'
```

Answer (score 0):

To print only filenames (without the path) use:

```
find . -type f -name \*.mp3 -printf "%f\n"
```